How to partition data in Spark when reading data from a MySQL table with string type primary key?
I'm reading data from a MySQL table in Spark. The table structure is like this:
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    id varchar(64),
    content varchar(64),
    primary key id(id)
)

My code in Spark is like this:
df = spark.read.format('jdbc').options(
                url=f"jdbc:mysql://...",
                driver='com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver',
                dbtable='my_table',
                user='',
                password='',
                partitionColumn='id',
                numPartitions=100,
                isolationLevel='NONE',
            ).load()

But seems like Spark doesn't support the use of a varchar column as partitionColumn. So how can I partition data in this table when reading by Spark? Consider this table is large.

It's recommended to use a numeric, date or timestamp column as the partitionColumn.

Yes, I know @VikasSharma. But if I don't have any usable numeric, date, or timestamp column in my table, and the table is large, how could Spark read from this table? Could Spark do partitioning by itself?

In that case, you can't use this option - instead, use jdbc function with predicates. This way you can make your reading parallel - but using the id column will still not be feasible here - because these are where conditions with a partition for each condition and using a primary key will create a partition for each row which doesn't seem like a good idea.
